# How to fetch line by line (row wise) data from excel file in c# using ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

I want to fetch data row wise from excel file.

Please find Image for Sample data.

I want to fetch this data row wise using ExcelDataReader.
Is there a way of doing it?

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH5DG.png)ack.imgur.com/jCSnx.png

```
using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
{
    DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
            UseHeaderRow = true
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying this code to fetch data. But it gives me 1st row as column header and then prints all the data same as it is.

Comment: Is there any code you've tried?

Comment: yes, i 've updated the ques

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first sheet as a DataTable by using `result.Tables[0]` then loop through the DataTable's rows. `result.Tables` is a collection of sheets inside your workbook.

```
using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
{
    DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
            UseHeaderRow = true
        }
    });

    DataTable dataTable = result.Tables[0];
    foreach(var row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        //Your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dumisani :)

Comment: You're welcome @KushagraVerma. Please mark as answer if it solved your problem, thanks.